# Как в админке увидеть русский текст?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$conn1 = new mysqli('1', 'r', 'p', 't');

// Check connection
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 
$query1 = "UPDATE test SET Столбик5 = 'ПУ' WHERE Столбик1='102693129074'";
if (mysqli_query($conn1, $query1)) {
echo "<br>"."Dobavleno";
  }else{
    echo "Oshibka".mysqli_error($conn1);
  }
```

Есть обычный код обновления данных в столбце, в сублиме сохраняю в UTF-8

https://ibb.co/hf9rDy6
и захожу в localhost/phpmyadmin там чебурашки.

потом сохраняю страничку в CP1251

https://ibb.co/kh0vLfp

и опять захожу в localhost/phpmyadmin и там опять другие чебурашки.

Вопрос как отобразить в админке русский текст в частности слово ПУ? ps MariaDB

Comment: попробуйте после соединения вызвать $conn1->set_charset("utf8"); или https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: ?? вот так после сохранения в utf-8 и в С1251

Comment: а сама база у вас создана в какой кодировке ? и таблицы в какой ?

Comment: вот так создавал http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6db1df7df5d137ff71aa8b7fdc7771e154d37d51

Comment: и как тут глянуть в какой кодировке сама база ?https://ibb.co/wMX6pdX

Comment: выйти на один уровень выше (на скриншоте вы внутри базы) нажать где "сервер  127.0.0.1" там будет список баз (напротив написано в какой кодировке она создана) я предполагаю что у вас всё по дефолту судя как вы создавали таблицы (не понял конечно что за звёздочки вместо названий полей) создайте базу используя кодировку utf-8 (create database t charset utf-8); и также добавьте charset при создании таблиц вот пример ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 (InnoDB или что-то другое уже выбирайте сами от ваших потребностей)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101180/discussion-between-noname2019-and-bloom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобравшись самое главное это кодировка, при создании базы:

https://ibb.co/2M808rK

И в самом коде

Поставить кодировку перед соданием таблицы

```
$conn = new mysqli('1', 'r', 'p', 't');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");  //обязательный параметр

$sql = "CREATE TABLE test (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
c* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
n* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
s* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
d* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
l* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
l* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

И непосредственно перед вводом данных

$conn1 = new mysqli('1', 'r', 'p', 't');

if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 
 mysqli_set_charset($conn1,"utf8"); //обязательный парметр

$query1 = "INSERT INTO test (**, **, **, **, **, **) VALUES ( '". $value1."','".$value2."','".$value3."','".$value4."' ,'".$value5."' ,'".$value6."' )";

if (mysqli_query($conn1, $query1)) {

echo "<br>"."Dobavleno";
  }else{
    echo "Oshibka".mysqli_error($conn1);
  }
```