# Как подключить кодировку UTF-8 в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть опрос на сайте, оно с помощью `sqlquery = select` берет вопросы с базы данных, и показывает на сайте, но сейчас вместо букв стоит символ `?`, как можно подключить и куда нужно подключать кодировку UTF-8, пробовал менять кодировку таблицу на `UTF-8 general_ci`, не помогло.

структура опроса выглядит так:

```
private function getData($sqlQuery) {
$result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
if(!$result){
die('Error in query: '. mysqli_error());
}
$data= array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$data[]=$row;            
}
return $data;
}
public function getPoll(){
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT pollid, question, options, votes, voters FROM '.$this->pollTable;
return  $this->getData($sqlQuery);
}
```

Comment: `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Спасибо за ответ, можете подсказать куда именно ставить этот кусок кода?

Comment: По ссылке пройдите, там много примеров использования.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1047583/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82

Comment: @bloom
Андрей, спасибо всем за помощь :)