# Не выводятся русские символы из базы MySql в Telegram bot

Tags: php, mysql, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для Телеграм. Серверная часть на PHP + MySql. 
По команде в телеге из базы MySql должна доставаться информация. Из базы отлично достаётся всё, кроме полей с русскими символами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Упрощённый вариант функции:

```
$bot->command('show', function ($message) use ($bot) {
$afisha_show = $db->query("SELECT name FROM afisha");
$answer = '';
while ($afisha = $afisha_show->fetch_assoc()) {
    //$answer = mb_detect_encoding($afisha['name']); - выводит UTF-8
    //$answer = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $afisha['name']); - не помогает
    //$answer = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $afisha['name']); - не помогает
    $answer = $afisha['name']; //ничего не выводит, если в поле name есть русские символы. Если в поле нет русских символов, то выводит то, что нужно
    //$answer = gettype($answer); - во всех случаях выводит string. То есть даже, если не отображает значения с русскими символами, всё равно gettype выводит string
}
$bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $answer);
});
```

Файл со скриптами в utf-8 без BOOM. 
Кодировка БД - utf8_general_ci. Другие поля из бд выводит нормально (id, url'ы картинок, ссылки и тд, т.к. там нет русских символов)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1047583/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82

Comment: База создаётся через phpmyadmin. Данные заносятся так же, ручками. Кодировка бд и таблиц - utf8_general_ci

Comment: mysqli_set_charset($conn1,"utf8");

Comment: аа, чёрт, сработало, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло, когда после соединения с бд (mysqli_connect) просто добавил строку:

```
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Спасибо [Bloom](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/336999/bloom) за наводку с функцией set_charset. Хотя, я всё ещё не понимаю, почему это решает проблему. Работа с бд ведётся только через phpmyadmin. Файл скрипта в utf-8, сама бд в utf8_general_ci...